# C++ WINAPI Charging

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to stop charging my laptop when it reaches 95% using WINAPI C++ how can I do that?

Tried digging through the winapi documentation but didn't find anything

Comment: I'm not sure such a thing is possible. Wouldn't charging happen at a lower level than the OS? Otherwise how can a laptop charge while it's shutdown?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: @molbdnilo You can increase the lifespan of laptop batteries by not charging to 100%, many manufacturers provide an on option to set the upper limit for this very reason.

Comment: Go into the BIOS of your computer and look for options there. There is nothing in Windows to do what you want. Cross site dupe: https://superuser.com/a/1529891

Comment: Yes, but why do you need to do it yourself? A quick web search turned up several solutions, at least for the major brands. Is your laptop very esoteric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try looking at the power management API?

Here is the code snippet:

```
#include <Windows.h>

GUID currentPowerScheme;
    PowerGetActiveScheme(NULL, &currentPowerScheme);
    SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS powerStatus;
    GetSystemPowerStatus(&powerStatus);
    ULONG batteryCapacity = powerStatus.BatteryLifePercent;
    DWORD batteryThreshold = 95;

if (batteryCapacity >= batteryThreshold) {
        GUID subGroup = GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE;
        GUID powerSetting = GUID_BATTERY_DISCHARGE_THRESHOLD;
        DWORD batteryStopThreshold = batteryThreshold * 100;
        POWER_SETTING_VALUE value;
        value.ValueLength = sizeof(DWORD);
        value.Data = &batteryStopThreshold;

        PowerWriteACValueIndex(NULL, &currentPowerScheme, &subGroup, &powerSetting, batteryStopThreshold);
   }
```